# Literature to the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, online-resources

I know few about algebraic number theory but recently I stumbled upon the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio. It seems to be a very interesting object to study, so now I'm curious what is known about this ring. Is there some literature about it?

Comment: What interesting facts do you know about it? I'm not aware of anything that makes it different from other quadratic extensions of $\Bbb Z$, so I'm interested.

Comment: I am researching about a generalization of fibonacci sequences, taking arbitrary starting values $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. I found that mapping such a sequence to the norm of the number $a+b\phi \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an interesing invariant and I think there is a 1-to-1-correspondece between a representing subset of the sequences and the possible values the norm of elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ can have.

Comment: Related: [Golden Number Theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/18589/)

Comment: I commented about it under one of the answers to the linked question, but I forgot to add a link to [the Icosians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian).

Answer (score 1):

Dodd, Number theory in the quadratic field with golden section unit, Polygonal Pub. House, 1983