# Usefulness of $\mathbb Z [\sqrt p] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, diophantine-equations

So I started examining FLT for $n=3$ with my professor, using properties of the Eisenstein integers. The professor made a diversion and spent a whole lecture proving that there are exactly two types of ideals in $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{ -5}]$, but we didn't make a connection to the FLT, and that left me wondering: Where are rings of the form $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ useful? Do they help us solve some other kind of Diophantine equation?

Comment: These can also be used to solve some Mordell equations

Comment: @rain1 I see, so they aren't much related to FLT?

Comment: I am the wrong person to describe it, but I would see they are very much related to FLT given that Kummer used "ideal numbers" (a precursor to the notion of an ideal) to prove FLT for *regular* primes. This was a much used avenue when proving non-existence of solutions to $x^p+y^p=z^p$ for a *fixed* prime $p$ (but for thousands of different $p$).

Comment: they can be applied to some specific cases of FLT absolutely

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/18660/581023 a very cool example