# Why does there seem to be a relation between the fifth roots of $32$ and $\varphi$ (the golden ratio)?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, golden-ratio

I have the following problem on one of my assignments:

find all five fifth roots of 32.

What I find interesting is how  $\varphi$  is related to the real component of most of the solutions. My intuition points me towards the definition of $\varphi$, namely  $\varphi$ = $\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}$

Here are the solutions:
$2$, $0.618+0.951i$, $-1.618+1.176i$, $-1.618-1.176i$, $0.618-1.902i$

Four of the solutions have real component (of what seems to be) either $-\varphi$ or $\varphi - 1$. It is not just a coincidence to do with rounding, it is exactly equal to $-\varphi$ and $\varphi - 1$ out to 10 decimal places.

Is there some deeper relation that I am missing? I was shocked to get this answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-prove-cos-frac2-pi-5-frac-1-sqrt54

Answer (score 5):

Note that

$$w^5=32e^{i2k\pi} \implies w_k= 2e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{5}}$$

with $k=0,1,2,3,4$ and for example

$$w_1 = 2\left(\cos \frac{2\pi}{5}+i \sin \frac{2\pi}{5}\right)$$

[image]

which is connected to golden ratio by the [golden triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_triangle_(mathematics))

[image]

(image modified from [credit 01](https://brilliant.org/wiki/roots-of-unity/), [credit 02](https://sriyantraresearch.com/Article/GoldenRatio/triangle%2072.jpg))

Comment: That triangle should have $\phi -1$ instead of $1$ on the lower left

Comment: Thanks! Good catch. I'm going to fix it!

Answer (score 5):

If $z^5=32$ then $$z=2 \exp\left(\frac {i2\pi k}5\right)=2 \left[\cos\left(\frac {2\pi k}5\right)+i\sin\left(\frac {2\pi k}5\right)\right]$$ for $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. The real part of $z$ is
$$2\cos\left(\frac {2\pi k}5\right)=\exp\left(\frac {i2\pi k}5\right)+\exp\left(-\frac {i2\pi k}5\right)=x+\frac1x,$$ where $x^5=1$. When $x=1$, this equals $2$. Otherwise, factor $x^5-1$ as
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^5-1&=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)\\
&=(x-1)x^2\left(x^2+x+1+\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}\right)\\
&=(x-1)x^2\left[\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2+\left(x+\frac1x\right)-1\right].
\end{aligned}
$$
So when $x\ne1$ we must have
$\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2+\left(x+\frac1x\right)-1=0$,
and the quadratic equation yields
$x+\frac1x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt 5}2$, which equals $-\phi$ or $\phi-1$.

Comment: [+1] but it would be good to add at the end "... giving rise to two quadratic equations whose solutions are the solutions to the initial problem".

Comment: Agreed (+1). Hope you don't mind I picked up from where you left off, I'll remove my answer if you think I borrowed too much.

Comment: @dxiv No problem, go right ahead. I'm happy to stop at determining the value of $x+\frac1x$, since this equals the real part of any fifth root of $32$.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the factorization in @grand_chat's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4676503/291201) one step further, and using the conjugate notation $\,\overline\varphi = -\dfrac{1}{\varphi} = - \varphi+1\,$ for the second root of the golden ratio equation:

$$
x^5 - 1 \;=\; (x-1)\,\big(x^2 + \varphi x + 1\big)\,\big(x^2 + \overline\varphi x + 1\big)
$$

This shows the presence of $\varphi$ in the factorization of $\,x^5 - 1\,$ over the reals, and confirms the connection with the $5^{th}$ roots of unity and associated trigonometric functions.

Perhaps more unexpectedly, this also facilitates an alternative proof of Fermat's Last Theorem in the special case $n=5$. Quoting from George Lowther's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/18660) under [Golden Number Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/golden-number-theory):

> Using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi]$ is a unique factorization domain in which we can decompose
> $$
> x^5+y^5=(x+y)(x^2+y^2-\varphi xy)(x^2+y^2-\bar\varphi xy)
> $$
> we can give a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem for the case of exponent $5$.